# Any help on chatterbot error: module 'time' has no attribute 'clock' error (python 3.10.1)

Tags: chatbot

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer

bot = ChatBot('Bot')
trainer = ListTrainer(bot)

trainer.train([
    'Hi how can I help you?',
    'howdy?',
    'hello?'
])

while True:
    request = input('You: ')
    response = bot.get_response(request)

    print('Bot: ', response)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on this control of the file of **compact.py**, you need to modify it from:

```
if win32 or jython:
  time_func = time.clock
else:
  time_func = time.time
```

to:

```
if win32 or jython:
 try: 
   preferred_clock = time.perf_counter
 except AttributeError: 
   preferred_clock = time.clock
else:
   time_func = time.time
```